# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server of Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2

I Enabled serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset serve by turning this configuration from production.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://assets.example.com'
```

All the assets started serving from https://assets.example.com from this url when I click on the assets link, 404 error page is rendered. I added a DNS A record for this subdomain too.

I am using Apache2 with Mod Passenger.

I am confused. Please suggest me the proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I removed the A Record of the assets subdomain and created a cname record of assets pointing it to the root domain.

```
CNAME assets is an alias of www.example.com
```

And then I added assets.example.com to the example.com.conf file as ServerAlias

```
ServerAlias assets.example.com
```

And further more to prevent assets.example.com from browsing itself I added a mod rewrite rule to redirect assets.example.com to www.example.com.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^assets\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Its working now.